# How can I say 'put jam on the bread'?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to say that I am putting jam on the bread, but 'put' is too boring of a word. What other word can I use? Example:

> I meticulously ___ Nutella on my bread.

Comment: You shouldn't be spreading Nutella on your bread if you're going to put jam on it. Not a good combination.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet you should try it.It's very palatable

Comment: I have tried it—found it absolutely disgusting. Two rights sometimes make a very wrong. Let's agree to disagree. ;-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet really? o_o

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet:  Don't forget "agreeably"! Agree to disagree agreeably. Oh, and don't forget the latinate phrase: Gustibus non est disputandum" (i.e., "In matters of taste, there can be no disputes" --literally, "about tastes, it should not be disputed/discussed").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

spread ([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spread))

> c :  to apply on a surface *spread butter on bread*

Example:

> I meticulously **spread** Nutella on my bread.